# java.io.IOException: Permission denied cannot create file

Tags: android

I follow this [tutorial](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) to take photo and save into device storage, but when I execute it, it got an exception

> ```
> java.io.IOException: Permission denied 
>  on line:
>
> File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
> ```

How to solve this?

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException
{
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

**--Edit--**
Here is my manifests

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.idea.takephoto">

<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!--<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>-->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

Comment: please declare this permission in manfest : android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As in the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#GetWritePermission), you need to write to the external storage, you must request the [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission in your [manifest file](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ...
</manifest>
```

If you use API 23 (Marshmallow) and above, you need to [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) because it's a [Dangerous Permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous).

Comment: All my problem is need to request the permission. Thank you

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue

Answer (score 9):

If your target api level is >=29 or you are using android 10 then please add following line in your app's manifest file in application tag

***android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"***

Comment: your answer is exactly correct. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Put permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and add `createTempFile` code in `try catch` block:

```
    File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = File.createTempFile(timeStamp, ".jpg", storageDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mCurrentPhotoPath = String.valueOf(Uri.fromFile(file));
    return file;
```

Answer (score 2):

add permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

if its  [above API 23 Storage permission  will do like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when using a device of android 10 api 29. I could solve it by replacing `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` with `context.getExternalFilesDir`.

Answer (score 0):

Write this tag in your project's manifest file, and give permission to your app from setting in your android phone before you are going to run it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

also add this in application field manifesto
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).