# Write a log to a txt file android

Tags: android, file, fileoutputstream, logfile

I have an application and some events i want to keep them inside a txt file in the Downloads.
i have the following piece of code but i get an exception (Permission denied). I have Android 10 Samsung S9 and i have granted all the permissions (write external storage)

```
 val externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            val myFile = File(externalStorageDir, "mylog.txt");

            if (myFile.exists()) {
                try {
                    val fostream = FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    val oswriter = OutputStreamWriter(fostream);
                    val bwriter = BufferedWriter(oswriter);
                    bwriter.write("Hi James. This is a message");
                    bwriter.newLine();
                    bwriter.close();
                    oswriter.close();
                    fostream.close();
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    myFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

The exception i get is this

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
W:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
W:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
W:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
W:     at package_name.utilities.SystemUtils$Companion.writefile(SystemUtils.kt:188)
W:     at package_name.ui.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.kt:37)
W:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
W:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
W:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
W:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
W:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
W:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
W:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
W:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
W:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
W:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

1) Why i cant write inside there?
2) Is there a library that can do that for me?

Comment: Android Q or 10  ?

Comment: Android 10. I got an update a few days ago

Comment: Can you also post the full error log that you are having?

Comment: As you can read here every day the last months that directory is not usable/writable under Q.

Comment: Well....is there any clear way that i can do what i want...?? Just to write inside a file that is accessable from the user

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053221/java-io-ioexception-permission-denied-cannot-create-file)

Comment: I was clear that the Permissions are Granted..!

Answer (score 0):

add `<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >`
  in you manifest. It's new thing in android Q.
for better answer check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56821320/11475673